# CSS-MediaQuerys not displayed on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I can't figure out, why my media-querys aren't working. Can someone tell me, why on all phones and tablets I have tested, the DIV is always yellow?

```css
.test {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height:500px;        
}  

@media all and (max-width: 360px) {
  .test {
    background-color:aqua;      
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 360px) {
  .test {
    background-color: #CCC;      
  }
}    
@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  .test {
    background-color: #FFE000;      
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test">sfds fsdf dsfsd</div>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added media query but you haven't added meta tag for it.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Add meta tag in your head section.

**Always write your code in order.**

```
@media all and (min-width: 360px) {
.test {
    background-color: #CCC;      
}
}
@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
.test {
    background-color: #FFE000;      
}
} 
@media all and (max-width: 360px) {
.test {
    background-color:aqua;      
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use higher resolutions first, so reorder queries like that:

```
@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
    .test {
        background-color: #FFE000;      
    }
} 
@media all and (min-width: 360px) {
    .test {
        background-color: #CCC;      
    }
}
@media all and (max-width: 360px) {
   .test {
        background-color:aqua;      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

wouldn't it be better like that?

```
 .test {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height:500px;
  background-color:aqua;      
}   

@media all and (min-width: 360px) {
  .test {
    background-color: #CCC;      
  }
}    
@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  .test {
    background-color: #FFE000;      
  }
}
```

what devices did you use?